# Creating a multicurrency Expert in mql4

Tags: mql4

I want to create a mutli-currency EA where users can add the currencies that they want their EA to trade in the input screen.

here is a piece of my code

```
string syms[] = {"EURUSD","USDJPY","GBPUSD"}; 

for(int s=0; s < ArraySize(syms); s++) 
{

}
```

I want to be able to add currencies to syms from the input screen.

Comment: Please show the steps you've already tried in order to come to a solution. This will give people more insight in the best way to help you

Comment: Your code has just a for loop with no contents? Sounds like you're pretty far from users being able to customize something. Maybe start with some tutorials?

Comment: Hello, I only wanted to know if there is a way of editing an array from the inputs screen

Comment: Hello Harrison, you cannot use array as an input parameter. Only simple types(`int`, `double`, etc).
If you want to get a list of pairs as inputs, the best way would be to get a list as a `string` with each pair separated by a comma or a special character. Then `OnInit()` you can split the `string` array into each pair.

Comment: Thank you TheLastShark for you reply,,,can I kindly get a code illustration for more clarity please

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *[" ... only wanted to know if there is a way of **editing an array** from the inputs screen ? "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771761/creating-a-multicurrency-expert-in-mql4#comment105694868_59771761)*

No, this was never possible in the MetaTrader4 Terminal / MQL4 until 2020/Q1.

### Possible Solutions :

1. one can create a non-blocking GUI-based dialogue, for defining, which tradeable symbols ought be included into the EA-operations, using the GUI-tools available for MMI and leaving a decision of a full-set or sub-set of the available choices inside a per-run semi-static configuration file.
2. one can create, as @TheLastShark proposed above, a primitive, one-stop setup, operating on interpreting a **`string config = "EURUSD | USDJPY | GBPUSD"; // split-char == 3-Byte SEQ of: " | "`**
3. the EA can communicate with external world using **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** tools, as often mentioned in other my posts, thus using a live-session remote-keyboard available for non-blocking, live-update of which of the traded symbols get added or removed from the EA-operations, with whatever business & trading logic one may wish to have - simply you have a remote-keyboard integrated with EA-embedded interactions for configurations and other live-session features.
4. the EA can communicate with external world using **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)**  tools, as in *3)*, yet the interaction is not an MMI but a fully M2M one, so the user interactions are cross-communicated via other technologies - WebPage->python->{*}->MetaTrader4 Terminal (MQL4) for all cases, when a remote-keyboard need not suffice or the user is "**too-slow-to-decide-and-react**" 
    <sub>*:o) which often we are ...*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
input  string symbol01="EURUSD";
input  string symbol02="GBPUSD";
input  string symbol03="USDJPY";
//---
string syms[] = {symbol01,symbol02,symbol03}; 

for(int s=0; s < ArraySize(syms); s++) 
{

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.